# diplaying latitude and longutude using geolocation API

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to display latitude and longitude using Modnizer geolocation api.
In my java script code when i try to execute my web application with the code.

```
if (Modernizr.geolocation ) {
// Find location... fill in.
//alert(" inside Modernizer");
// Not coming here if i use if(Modernizr.geolocation)

 navigator.geolocation
.getCurrentPosition(location_found, location_error);
```

}

Nothing happens when i press the set location button. but when i try to execute the web application without `if (Modernizr.geolocation )
{
}`

I get the latitude and longitude displayed on the web page. y the control is not passing from the if (Modernizr.geolocation ) statement .

Comment: It sounds to me like you might have an issue loading the Modernizr script. (Modernizr doesn't provide the geolocation API, it only detects if the browser supports it, so you can avoid running the code on unsupported browsers).

Comment: i am using this on main jsp page <script src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>  . it must have to work... thanks for the answer..

Comment: You are missing the protocol. Add `//` before `modernizr.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. The URL was wrong

Answer (score 0):

gThe URL I mentioned in the script was wrong. Thats is reason my code is not goint in the if (Modernizr.geolocation ).

I downloaded  the Js form the modnizer web and  placed it in my project. now every thing is working fine.  Thans to JOsef Engelfrost